# Unity 3d OnClick to ignore specific layer (or fire only on specific laye

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, raycasting

Is there a way to make standard unity OnClick even fire while ignoring specific layers?
For example, i have army of soldiers on layer "Units" and ground on Layer "Ground". When i click on soldier, it gets selected. Then i click on the ground, soldier moves there. But if i click on the ground obscured by another soldier, it fires even for that soldier rather than ground, cos he is closer to the camera.
Can i ignore "Units" layer without rewriting whole mouse click even handling and using my custom raycast?

EDIT:
code is here, dont thnk it will show anything but

```
static public void Interact2(Cell target) //this fires from OnClick
    {
        if (GameLogic.Mode == mode.move)
        {
            grid.MoveTo(target);
            if (selected.actionsAvilable[action.move])
                selected.actionsAvilable[action.move] = false;
            else
                selected.actionsAvilable[action.standard] = false;
            GameLogic.Mode = GameLogic.mode.normal;
        }
    }
```

MORE EDIT:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
        if (!UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            GameLogic.Interact2(this);
    }
```

Comment: What does your current coded look like?

Comment: cant get used to RETURN just sending comment instead of getting new row

Comment: You can edit your question and add that code there and also the language tag

Comment: I was actually asking for the current code you use to detect the click on the 3D Object

Comment: @Programmer he's not using any special code, it's all handled by Unity.

Comment: @Arshia001 I know. There are more than 3 ways to detect clicks on an object in Unity. I want to see which method OP is using so that we don't provide a solution that OP is already using and having problems with.

Comment: My money's on the event system.

Comment: Yes, its EventSystem

Comment: Its Currently have !UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() to ignore clicks on soldiers so they dont get selected before the selected one moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PhysicsRaycaster/PhysicsRaycaster2D/GraphicsRaycaster components have an Event Mask property which allows you to limit the layers they raycast against. You should update that property from code when you want to block/allow certain layers.

Comment: Can i changethis property for standard OnClick raycast? If so, where?

Comment: Assuming your physics raycaster is on the main camera (which it should be): `Camera.main.GetComponent<UnityEngine.EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster>().eventMask =  desired_layer_mask`

Comment: i use MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown, so there are no PhysicsRaycaster i dont think. I have Graphics one for UI.

Comment: Oh. That's not a good thing to do. Use the event system as per https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html . You can't so what you want with onmousedown.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had an idea of disabling colliders on all the units temporarily (as a crutch) but that does not feels like performance-friendly thing.

Comment: Doesn't feel like it because it's not performance-friendly at all. You should generally try to use the event system as much as you can, it's unbelievably feature-rich and usable by Unity's standards. Anyway, if this solved your problem, click the green check mark to mark this as the answer so others with the same problem will have an easier time finding it.